# How do I run a C++ program in Xcode 4?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, xcode4

I want to write a C++ program in Xcode on my Mac. I wrote this basic one to test it. When I build, I get a "Build Successful" message.

However, I cannot run it! If I hit Command+R nothing happens. When I go to Project->Run the Run option is disabled.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "helo" << endl;

}
```

Comment: How did you create the new project. You have to select command line application > C++ Application in the new file dialog.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

1. Launch XCode
   [image: Step 1]
2. In the "Choose template" box, pick Mac OS X, then Command Line Tool. Press Next
   [image: Step 2]
3. Give your project a name, select C++ as the type
   [image: Step 3]
4. You should see a new project with main.cpp
   [image: Step 4]
5. press the Run button
6. At the bottom of the screen, under All Output you should see:

   **Hello, World!**
   Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: I just got a "guru" badge for this answer. While nice, I think this is a clear sign that Apple needs to take a careful look at their documentation.

Comment: By default, it creates a `main.cpp` file, which contains a **Hello World** message to print. When I try to add another `C++` file to that project, which prints, say **Foo**, clicking the `Run` button still outputs **Hello World** only. How do I create multiple `C++` files under that project and  run them individually, without one referencing or depending upon the others?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - that is a good standalone question. Please post it as a question and you are much more likely to get a good answer!

Comment: Any ideas on how to run individual files in a project ?

Comment: @iota - another good standalone question.

Everyone else - Comments are not the place for questions. Please post new questions and you will get better answers. Additionally, others will be able to find your answers in the future.

Comment: @ObscureRobot  posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604251/mac-what-is-the-best-way-to-have-multiple-c-c-files-in-a-project-and-be-able

Comment: @ObscureRobot build failed due to "
Showing Recent Issues
No signing certificate "Mac Development" found:  No "Mac Development" signing certificate matching team ID "*********" with a private key was found." Is it possible to run c++ in Xcode with free personal team?