# Xcode not showing anything in console with C++

Tags: c++, xcode4.2, printf, cout

I was just trying to use Xcode for a very small C++ project, and wanted to see

some prints in the console, the thing is I did not see anything.

I tried to run a very simple code instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
printf("here");
return 0;
}
```

but still, nothing in Xcode console.

any idea why?

**EDIT:**

adding snapshot of the program:

[image: xcode]

**EDIT 2:**

found this,

and it's working:

[How do I run a C++ program in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911076/how-do-i-run-a-c-program-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image doesn't show that you ran the program, only that you built it. Look at the Log Navigator (the last one, ⌘7) and see if there are any logs for 'Debug one' after 'Build one'. To run the program use Product > Run or ⌘R.

Comment: for some reason i cant use ⌘R, or Product > Run. it is marked in grey color as in  i cant push it. why is that?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know why that would be. Your screen shot also shows some .xcconfig files which I don't think is normal for a command line app. Maybe try creating a new project, Choose Mac OS X > Application > Command Line Tool.

Answer (score 3):

That should work fine. Are you sure that you had the console displayed? Try command-shift-C or choose View->Debug Area->Activate Console.

If that doesn't help, try running your program from a Terminal window. Does the program display the expected output?

Comment: i really dont know how to run it from terminal window, but activate console is exactly what i did and still nothing.

Comment: @Itzik984 Does the console window have 'Debugger Output' selected in the little chooser thing? If so change it to 'All Output'

Comment: @Itzik984 did you run the project? up at the top it only says 'Build one: Succeeded' not 'Finished running one'

Comment: @bames53 i am pushing the PLAY button but it only say 'Build one: Succeeded' and i really cant see  'Finished running one'.
im using Command+R.

Comment: Use ⌘R or ⌃⌘R instead of ⇧⌘R. ⇧⌘R builds without running.

Comment: @bames53 i am using  ⌘R  but it does nothing. it cannot run the program for some reason. (also product->run shows in grey 'disabled' button.

Comment: @bames53 i really have no idea why this is happening... why im unable to run project... ill guess ill re-install xcode and hope for the best :(

Comment: @Itzik984 did you try creating a new command line tool project?

Comment: @Itzik984 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8559/discussion-between-bames53-and-itzik984)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like when you created a new project (File > New > Project... ), you selected "C/C++ Library".  Since libraries don't output to the console directly, that explains why Run was greyed out for you and running it doesn't output to the console.

Instead, you need to create a new project and select "Command Line Tool" template in the Application section, and build your program from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing Shift+Command+R. That should compile your program and open it in a terminal window.

Comment: ⇧⌘R will build it for running, but won't run it.

Comment: That's what Command+R does, at least in my version of xCode. I don;t see why it would be different though in his version.

Comment: It sounds like your keyboard commands are customized. By default ⇧⌘R builds the project but won't run it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to add "\n" after "here"
I don't know why but it works for me.
Hope someone can explain it for me.