# run c in xcode shows nothing

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, xcode6

I am trying to run c in xcode 6,however I run the ⌘R it shows build Succeeded but nothing in console,but I can run it in ubuntu Linux's gcc,here is my c code in ubuntu Linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a[100],i,j,t,n;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=n-i;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]<a[j+1])
        { t=a[j]; a[j]=a[j+1]; a[j+1]=t; }
    }
}
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    printf("%d ",a[i]);

getchar();getchar();
return 0;

}
```

when I run it in gcc it's ok,

```
ubuntu#vi ac9.c
ubuntu#gcc -o ac9 ac9.c
ubuntu#./ac9
```

the file name is ac9.c

but move it to mac's xcode ,I run the ⌘R it shows build Succeeded but nothing in console,
and here is my code in xcode 6.4

[image]

Comment: please post code, not pictures of code…

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to signal to the Operating System to dump what is in the output buffer to the screen before the calls to `getchar()`.

The easiest way to do that is to print a newline.

```
// ...
// print a newline; force OS to dump output buffer
printf("\n"); // or puts("");
getchar(); getchar();
// ...
```

One other way is to call `fflush()`

```
// ...
// force OS to dump output buffer
fflush(stdout);
getchar(); getchar();
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Xcode not showing anything in console with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576375/456814),

> Your image doesn't show that you ran the program, only that you built
>   it. Look at the Log Navigator (the last one, ⌘7) and see if there are
>   any logs for 'Debug one' after 'Build one'. To run the program use
>   Product > Run or ⌘R.

Comment: I run the ⌘R it shows build Succeeded but nothing is console

Comment: see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576258/xcode-not-showing-anything-in-console-with-c

Comment: When you copy someone else's answer, make sure you link to it and quote the copied text, otherwise you're plagiarizing them.