# Mac: What is the best way to have multiple c++/c files in a project and be able run/debug them individually in Mac

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, eclipse-cdt, dev-c++

I have tried eclipse cdt, but again it has got gdb problems with osx yosemite and it doesn't suppoort lldb.

In xcode I can run a single file. since it builds the whole project.

I am looking for something like c-free, dev-c++ etc.